# Working with URL parameters in custom Kibana plugin

Tags: elastic-stack, kibana-7, kibana-plugin

I am working on a custom plugin to Kibana (7.5.2). The plugin is of type 'app'. I would like to be able to pass parameters to this plugin in order to pre-load some data from Elasticsearch. I.e., I need to provide users with some specific URLs containing parameters that will be used by the plugin to show only a relevant portion of data.

My problem is that I was not able to find sufficient documentation on this and I do not know what the correct approach should be. I will try to summarize what I know/have done so far:

1. I have read the [official resources on plugin development](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.5/plugin-development.html)
2. I am aware of the fact that **_g** and **_a** URL parameters are used to pass state in Kibana applications. However, a) I am not sure if this is the correct approach in my case and b) I also failed to find any information on how my plugin should access the data from these parameters.
3. I checked the sources of other [known plugins](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.5/known-plugins.html), but again, failed to find any clues.
4. I am able to inject some configuration values using `injectUiAppVars` in the `init` method of my plugin (`index.js`) and retrieve these values in my app (`main.js`):

   **index.js:**

```
export default function (kibana) {
 return new kibana.Plugin({
   require: ['elasticsearch'],
   name: ...,
   uiExports: {
     ...
   },

   ...

   init(server, options) { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
     server.injectUiAppVars('logviewer', async () => {
       var kibana_vars = await server.getInjectedUiAppVars('kibana');
       var aggregated_vars = { ...kibana_vars, ...{ mycustomparameter: "some value" } }
       return aggregated_vars
     });

   ...
   }
 });
}
```

**main.js**

```
   import chrome from 'ui/chrome';
   . . . 
   const mycustomparameter = chrome.getInjected('mycustomparameter');
```

Providing that I manage to obtain parameters from URL, this would allow me to pass them to my app (via `mycustomparameter`), but again, I am not sure if this approach is correct.

5. I tried to get some help via the Elastic forum, but did not receive any answer yet.

**My questions**
1. Is there any source of information on this particular topic? I am aware of the fact that the plugin API changes frequently, hence I do not expect to find an extensive documentation. Maybe a good example?

2. Am I completely off course with the way I am trying to achieve it?

Thanks for reading this, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your method for retrieving the injected variables using `chrome` is very useful. An [example](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/reading-config-env-variable-inside-kibana-plugin/167643/5) at the Elastic forum was more complicated.